# Segmentation Fault when using qsort on struct in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, qsort

I'm trying to make a program that reads a binary file that contains several structs and prints a sorted version of that data, but whenever I try to run qsort it gives a segmentation fault. I know that it's qsort that's causing the segmentation error, since removing it allowed the program to run smoothly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Data_s {
double dest;
float dec;
char colour[9];
short dress;
int experience;
char voyage;
char care;
unsigned short distance;
int cars;
char letter;
unsigned char quick;
char maelstrom;
unsigned int station;
short rat;
long macey;
float limb; 
} Data;

int compare(const void *pa, const void * pb);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    
    int fn = fileno(fp);
    struct stat sb;
    fstat(fn,&sb);
    
    #define NUM (int)(sb.st_size/sizeof(Data))
    int i;
    Data *arr[NUM];

    for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        arr[i] = (Data *)malloc(sizeof(Data));
        fread(&arr[i]->dest,sizeof(arr[i] -> dest),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->dec,sizeof(arr[i]->dec),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->colour,sizeof(arr[i]->colour),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->dress,sizeof(arr[i]->dress),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->experience,sizeof(arr[i]->experience),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->voyage,sizeof(arr[i]->voyage),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->care,sizeof(arr[i]->care),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->distance,sizeof(arr[i]->distance),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->cars,sizeof(arr[i]->cars),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->letter,sizeof(arr[i]->letter),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->quick,sizeof(arr[i]->quick),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->maelstrom,sizeof(arr[i]->maelstrom),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->station,sizeof(arr[i]->station),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->rat,sizeof(arr[i]->rat),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->macey,sizeof(arr[i]->macey),1,fp);
        fread(&arr[i]->limb,sizeof(arr[i]->limb),1,fp);
    }
    qsort(arr,NUM,sizeof(Data),compare);
    for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]->dest);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int compare (const void * pa, const void * pb)
{
  const Data *p1 = (Data *)pa;
  const Data *p2 = (Data *)pb;
  return ( p1->dest- p2->dest);
}
```

Comment: Try running code through valgrind locate the problem source.

Comment: Why are you declaring `arr` as `Data *arr[NUM];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `qsort`, it's your comparing function. You made a mistake in `compare`.

The comparator gets pointers to your array's items, and those items are *pointers to* `Data` structures, not `Data` themselves. To handle them properly you need

```
int compare (const void * pa, const void * pb)
{
    const Data **p1 = (Data **)pa;
    const Data **p2 = (Data **)pb;
    return ( (*p1)->dest- (*p2)->dest);
}
```

There is a minor flaw in the above code - `pa` and `pb` are 'pointers to `const` *something*'. The cast `(Data **)pa` converts a type to a 'pointer to *a pointer to Data*', which lacks the `const` qualifier.  The correct cast is

```
  Data * const *p1 = (Data * const *)pa;
  Data * const *p2 = (Data * const *)pb;
```

which makes 'a pointer to a `const` pointer to Data'. This declares that the resulting `p1` and `p2` pointers can not be used to modify our array's items.

We can add another qualifier to be even more safe:

```
    const Data * const *p1 = (const Data * const *)pa;
    const Data * const *p2 = (const Data * const *)pb;
```

declares resulting pointers as 'a pointer to a `const` pointer to `const` Data' – not only the array's items are immutable, but also pointed `Data` objects are protected against changes.

Comment: When I try to compile the code, it says that (Data **) pa is an incompatible pointer type

Comment: @kirinM You're right, I added a fix to the answer.

Comment: Tricky. But I feel it would be easier anyway to not have an array of pointers but just the Data anyway. As the size is predetermined

Comment: @KamiKaze That's definitely correct. :) Even if the size is unknown in advance or too large for the automatic variables' storage, we can allocate dynamically the whole array of `Data`s. It is faster in execution (one allocation instead of, say, 500 – and same with deallocations), faster in use (an offset along the array instead of dereferencing a new pointer) and more memory-efficient (one allocated block to maintain).